# How to communicate with the nodeJS server setup in the Google cloud virtual machines(Windows server) through internet?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, socket.io

I am developing a chat app in android using soocket.io. This app needs to communicate with one of the nodejs application listening at port `4000` in my Google cloud Virtual machine through internet.
GCP provided internal and external IP. When I run the `internalIP:4000` in browser of VM, I can see it is running fine. But outside of the VM, when I run `ExternalIP:4000` it is giving error. I don't know why it is not working.

This is the firewall configurations
[image]

Answer (score 1):

So you already established that your service is running fine and is on a correct port (4000).

Now you have to expose to the Internet. By default [this port is blocked for any traffic](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls#default_firewall_rules) by [GCP's Firewall](https://console.cloud.google.com/networking/firewalls/list). This way only ports for SSH, RDP or ICMP protocols are open to be able to connect to your VM's. If you need non-standard port you have to create apropriate firewall rule.

You can create it by running using Cloud Shell or running this in your VM's command prompt:

```
gcloud compute --project=my-project-name firewall-rules create my-app-port \
--direction=INGRESS --priority=1000 --network=default \
--action=ALLOW --rules=tcp:4000 --source-ranges=0.0.0.0/0 \
--target-tags=my-app-server
```

or create it using [Cloud Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/networking/firewalls/add). Have a look at the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-firewalls#creating_firewall_rules) if you have any doubts.

In my example I used `my-app-server` network tag. You need to [add it to your VM](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/add-remove-network-tags#adding_viewing_and_removing_tags) that runs the app server - otherwise the rule won't work. It's best to do it this way since you're only exposing one additional port on a single VM which is safest possible solution.

Comment: @wojtek_B thanks for the answer. I will try that.

Comment: @wojtek_B I configured the firewall rule to allow connection at tcp:4000. but still when I run from the external Ip it is showing "site can't reach" message in the browser.

Comment: Does the VM in question have access to Internet ? Can you ping you VM from the outside ? Please update your question with the output of the `gcloud compute firewall-rules describe firewall_rule_name`.

Comment: @Wojtek_B I can able to ping the VM from out side. I updated my question with out put of "gcloud compute firewall-rules describe firewall_rule_name" please find.

Comment: Do you use [Identity Aware Proxy](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/concepts-overview#how_iap_works) ? It may be blocking your connections. Try accessing your app from a different VM in the same VPC network - does it work ? Try from another VM or from the Internet: `curl VM'sIP:4000` and paste the results in your original question.